# Shift all elements in a 2-dimensional array down

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I wanted to know if there's a good way of decrementing the row-index of all non-zero elements in a 2-dimensional array. For example, to shift all non-zero elements to the left:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1] =>
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

A simple algorithm to do this would obviously be:

```
for (int[] row : array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length - 1; i++) {
        row[i] = row[i + 1];
    }

    row[row.length - 1] = 0;
}
```

I could also do it like this:

```
for (int[] row : array) {
    System.arraycopy(row, 1, row, 0, row.length - 1);
    row[row.length - 1] = 0;
}
```

The simple algorithm to shift all elements down from *index*:

```
for (int col = 0; col < arr[0].length; col++) {
    for (int row = index; row > 0; row--) {
        arr[row][col] = arr[row - 1][col];
    }
}
```

I cannot, however, do `System.arraycopy` when doing this with row indices.

Now what I wanted to know is, is there a better way of shifting the elements *down* other than looping through the whole matrix like above?

Comment: What are you going to use this for? Can you use linked lists where you just take the tail? Can you use circular arrays?

Comment: I'm implementing a tetris game. When a row is filled, all rows above it should drop down one level (the gamearea is represented in a 2-dimensional matrix). I figured I could store the elements in a `[x][y]` array instead of `[y][x]`, and then I could do the arraycopy on it, but I figured I'd ask anyway in case a great method surfaces.

Comment: You can have 2 such arrays, and use System.arrayCopy from one to another. You still get the speed, and if you re-use the arrays you don't hog the GC. Looping here might be too slow for a game (depends on board size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now what I wanted to know is, is there a better way of shifting the elements down other than looping through the whole matrix like above?

Define better :-).

There is no way to get rid of the outer loop that is going to improve performance or (IMO) readability.

As for the inner loop, the performance benefit of using arraycopy is likely to be small ... or even negative, if the arrays are small.

If you have evidence that the performance will really make a practical difference, then I would recommend:

1. Profile the code to verify this.
2. Trying both (and other) alternatives and *measuring* the affect on your overall application.